# Passing data through scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use the function "example_func" in the SendScript but appears this problem:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object SendScript.Menu_Action_GoToArtists (System.String sceneName)
>   (at Assets/Scenes/SendScript.cs:23)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SendScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private ReceiveScript receiveScript;

    public void Start () 
    {
        receiveScript = FindObjectOfType<ReceiveScript>();
    }

    public void Menu_Action_GoToArtists(string sceneName)
    {
        receiveScript.example_func();
    }
}
```

and

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ReceiveScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public void example_func()
    {
        print("It works");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FindObjectOfType returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090855/findobjectoftype-returning-null)

Comment: "    receiveScript.example_func();
" this is where is shows me the error

Comment: how can i solve it?

Comment: Are you sure your ReceiveScript is attached to a game object?

Comment: I would suggest debugging the Start-method to make sure your script is found. Maybe your game object with the scrip attached is not yet loaded or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

A few things can be wrong and cause this issue:

1) your ReceiveScript Component is not set to any object in the world (most likely scenario)

2) The start call does not find the the ReceiveScript (see 1)
you can check easily by doing this in Start:

```
public void Start () 
{
    if(receiveScript = FindObjectOfType<ReceiveScript>())
    {
        Debug.Log("Found Script!");
        return;
    }
    Debug.Log("Didn't find script!");
}
```

Try that and see what it says.